# Запросить у пула (c3p0) состояние сервера

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

Я знаю, что у *c3p0* есть возможность прицепить кастомный класс и проверять ИМ состояние бд.

Но в той версии, что прицеплена к *hibernate*, нет поддержки соответсвующих команд у класса *Connection*.

Как лучше проверять жизнеспособность бд?

Может у этого пула есть отдельно взятые команды для запроса этой информации?

Answer (score 1):

Есть в c3p0 настройки для проверки соединения с БД.

- [Вот ссылка на вопрос и ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015001/check-if-connection-of-database-is-live-in-hibernate/16025112#16025112).
- [Здесь есть пример конфигурации в вопросе и описание дополнительных свойств в ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978617/mysql-connection-and-hibernate-c3p0-settings-timeout-after-8-hours/14979602#14979602).
- [Здесь примеры "пустых" SQL-запросов для разных СУБД](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684244/dbcp-validationquery-for-different-databases/10684260#10684260).

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?